# EA Addin ActivityParameter Content

Tags: add-in, enterprise-architect

I created an addin in C#. When I get an activityParameter Element via API `Repository.GetElementByID(..)` or `Repository.GetElementByGuid(..)`, I can not find Type and Direction in information provided by these two APIs.
Via `Repository.SQLQuery(...)` I see the Type in Pdata1, but still can not find Direction, also it will be better if I can find Type in the ***Element*** object

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will find these in `t_xref` with *name="CustomProperties"*. It's in the *Description* and you will likely be able to decode the CSV therein.

Not sure, but likely the API offers them under *CustomProperties*.

Comment: If the type is in PDATA1, it might be exposed by the API in `MiscData(0)`

Comment: Found direction in CustomProperties, I need now to see where can I find the Type. These are the parameters inside CustomProperties:
Name Value Type
[0] "direction" string
[1] "isStream" string
[2] "isException" string
[3] "effect" string
[4] "default" string
[5] "isConst" string
[6] "isOrdered" string
[7] "isUnique" string

Comment: @GeertBellekens  MiscData(0) returns empty string

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this function will be useful for others

```
    /* Function to get the parameter value of an Element */
    private string GetElementParameterValue(Element element, string parameterName)
    {

        foreach (CustomProperty property in element.CustomProperties)
        {
            if (property.Name == parameterName)
                return property.Value;
        }

        //return null
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: I updated the method with EA.CustomProperty and it works . If I try GetType on an element from CustomProperties receive System.__ComObject.  I can not find a proper EA documentation where I can see all the objects available for .net Addin. Thanks for help

Comment: all documentation for the API is here: https://sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/15.2/automation/reference.html